# Spring error during dependancy injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am learning Spring and writing a simple program to inject a property into a POJO. Below is the main class --

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        MySpring sm = (MySpring)context.getBean("myspring");
        System.out.println(sm);
    }

}
```

The POJO is below --

```
  public class MySpring {
    public String count;
    void setcount(String val){
        this.count = val;
    }
    String getcount(){
        return count;
    }

}
```

And the config file is below --

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
  <bean id="myspring" class="MySpring" >
   <property name="count" value="PowerShell" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

However I am getting the following error when I run the test.java class --

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myspring' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'count' of bean class [MySpring]: Bean property 'count' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at 
.....
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.main(test.java:7)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'count' of bean class [MySpring]: Bean property 'count' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
```

I know this is a common error but am not able to find the root cause as everything seems fine. Any pointers on what might be the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bean property 'count' is not writable or has an invalid setter method*

You need to have a setter for `count` property

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, But if you see my POJO MySpring, I do have a setter for the count property..void setcount(String val){ this.count = val; }

Comment: Is there any specific convention that needs to be adhered too.

Comment: Yes setter needs to be public and convention is setCount(), the first character should be in CAP. Best is if you use IDE to create the setters for you.

Comment: @user496934 : Also, I'd suggest using your getter/setters with `public` rather than using the default access specifier to avoid access issues at runtime. Also, if you are using an IDE like Eclipse, you can use the menu options to make Eclipse generate the getter/setters for you...

Comment: @Anshu : i dont think that for dependency injection, we have to set the variable as public. We can keep it private as well but the getters-setters should be public. Please make it clear

Comment: @Gunjan, You are correct. I never mentioned that the variable needs to be public. only getters and setters need to be public.

Answer (score 0):

The setter should be `setCount()`, not `setcount()`

Answer (score 0):

The code `void setcount(String val){` should be changed to "C" in Caps

```
void setCount(String val)
```

Starting Letter after get/set should be in CAPS. same applies for getter method also.

Answer (score 0):

you need to following the Javabeans naming convention when naming the setter/getters. This is a requirement for the BeanIntrospection framework.
Following should work:

```
void setCount(String val){
  this.count = val;
}

String getCount(){
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `Spring` strictly follow the `naming convention` of bean' properties to inject.
`Properties` are always `accessed via method calls on their owning object`. For `readable` property there will be a `getter` `method` to read there value,for `writable` property there will be a `setter` `method` to write there value.

So in your case `Spring's IOC container implementation ApplicationContext` try to instantiate the `bean`(MySpring) and `inject` the property of your `MySpring` class which is `count`, for `injecting purpose container try to finding out the getCount() getter method inside your MySpring class`, but there is no such method inside your `class` which falls to `Exception`.

Modified your bean

```
class MySpring
{
    private String count;

    /**
     * @return the count
     */
    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * @param count the count to set
     */
    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring IoC container supports setter injectionas described in the JavaBeans Specification (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

It searches for something like "setCamelVarName()" and it lowercases the first letter after “set” in the method name and use the rest of the method name as-is for deducing the property name.
So, to set the "count" attribute in your class you should declare a public method `public void setCount(int count)` and not `public void setcount(int count)`.
This last one is against good Java development practices too anyhow.